# Probability problem: In a box of k balls, there are m white balls, n black balls, and the remaining balls are green.

Tags: calculus, probability

We draw a ball from the box 5 times with replacement.
Calculate the probability that in this procedure all colors will be drawn.
I would be very happy if you can help me with this task.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have $m$ white balls, $n$ black balls, and $i$ green balls.

The probability of getting only one or two colors (we double count the one color cases and so we need to subtract that):
$P = \frac{(m+n)^5  +  (n+i)^5 + (i+m)^5 - (m^5 + n^5+i^5) }{k^5}$

The probability of getting three colors: $P_0 = 1-P.$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for the correction. Solution edited.